# Scientific foundation of Mézières method

Tags: physiotherapy

my orthopedist told me I should begin the "Mézières method" for some back problems I have.I looked it up on the Internet to find out what is it but I could not find any research that found it works (i looked it up on google and on google scholar, but I don't know where else to look up).
My question is, is there any scientific foundation of this kind of physiotherapy or is it just some alternative medicine like homeopathy or acupuncture?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a lot of scientific foundation for it at the moment but [there is a clinical trial](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT03738306) on it.

There is however, one pilot study paper on the effects of 2 physiotherapy programs on pain perception, muscular flexibility, and illness impact ([Valencia et al. 2009](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/B_Fradejas/publication/23719179_Effects_of_2_Physiotherapy_Programs_on_Pain_Perception_Muscular_Flexibility_and_Illness_Impact_in_Women_With_Fibromyalgia_A_Pilot_Study/links/56693b2e08ae9da364ba3f54/Effects-of-2-Physiotherapy-Programs-on-Pain-Perception-Muscular-Flexibility-and-Illness-Impact-in-Women-With-Fibromyalgia-A-Pilot-Study.pdf)).  The comparison between kinesiotherapy and active muscular stretching with Global Myofascial Physiotherapy according to the Mézières method found that

> Patients had achieved a statistically significant reduction in the severity of the disease and improved their flexibility level by the end of the program, but had returned to initial values after follow-up. Significant differences were not observed between the 2 treatment groups in the initial values or in the results at the end of the program or after the follow-up, so neither program proved better than the other.

### References

Valencia, M., Alonso, B., Alvarez, M. J., Barrientos, M. J., Ayán, C., & Sánchez, V. M. (2009). Effects of 2 physiotherapy programs on pain perception, muscular flexibility, and illness impact in women with fibromyalgia: a pilot study. *Journal of manipulative and physiological therapeutics, 32*(1), 84-92. doi: [10.1016/j.jmpt.2008.07.003](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmpt.2008.07.003)

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be a lot of actual scientific research on the subject, but you can follow a paper trail for a while:

The Daily Telegraph (an English newspaper) has an [article](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/health/4967492/Mezieres-Method-Perfection-isallin-the-body.html) on the subject, and references two people:

- [Joel Carbonnel](http://www.positivehealth.com/therapist/joel-carbonnel-alexander-and-mezieres-technique)
- [Professor M Jesel](https://www.researchgate.net/scientific-contributions/2127204326_M_Jesel)

The article also states:

> But in recent years, the University of Strasbourg has taken up the Mézières flag and is developing the therapy under the name Postural Reconstruction.

Looking up Postural Reconstruction doesn't get you far either, you arrive at:

- [Britannia Body Works](https://www.britanniabodyworks.com/services/physiotherapy-calgary/postural-reconstruction/https://)
- [Reconstruction Postural](https://www.reconstruction-posturale.com/documentation#articles-et-livres-scientifiques)
- [Orthomorphy](http://www.orthomorphy.co.uk/mezieres/an-overview/)

with the only remotely looking scientific article coming from Science Direct:

> https://www.sciencedirect.com/sdfe/pdf/download/eid/1-s2.0-S1779012316303825/first-page-pdf